# boost::algorithm::to_upper/to_lower ok for utf8? boost::locale not necessary?

Tags: c++, string, boost, internationalization

I've read in several places that boost::algorithm::to_upper/to_lower are not ok for utf8:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions.html
- [How to convert std::string to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/stl-string-to-lower-case)
- [Working with UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967878/working-with-utf8)

But on my system, ubuntu 12.4.1 32 bits with boost 1.46, and locale en_GB.UTF-8, everything looks fine,as long as I pass the locale Eg:

```
std::locale englishUTF8locale("en_GB.UTF-8")
boost::algorithm::to_upper_copy(L"ü", englishUTF8locale) -> L"Ü"
boost::algorithm::to_lower_copy(L"и", englishUTF8locale) ->L"И"
```

What is worth noting is that it works when using std::wstring, but not when using std::string

So, boost::locale is not really necessary? My problem is that I can only use boost 1.46, and locale was created for 1.48

Comment: So... do you have a question?

Comment: The linked Boost page gives an example and explanation where `boost::algorithm::to_upper_copy` gives an incorrect result...

Comment: @aschepler That's because in the example they don't pass any locale to the boost::algorithm functions. With the locale I do get the capital "Ü".

Comment: No, the mistake is that the uppercase of "ß" is "SS", not "ß".  But since `boost::algorithm::to_lower` returns a single code point, there's no way to fix that without using an algorithm which outputs strings.

Comment: @aschepler: +1, but your comment should have been an answer.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks, actually there's also a ẞ (slightly different than ß), but SS is the correct way. I haven't found any other case in "typical languages", though.